# Angular 2 not refreshing the view after the value change of a variable?

Tags: angular

So, I've been pulling my hair out for the last two hours searching for the answer. 
I have  a simple AppComponent like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserDataService}  from '../services/user-data.service';

@Component({
selector: 'myapp',
template: `
<h1>Angular 2 app inside a desktop app</h1>
<div *ngIf="data">
    {{data}}
</div>
`,
})

export class AppComponent{
     public data : Object;

     constructor(private userDataService : UserDataService) {}

     ngOnInit(){
      this.data=this.userDataService.getUserData(); 
     }

}
```

What I want is to import the data from a configuration file from UserDataService, which looks like this:

```
  import {Injectable}    from '@angular/core';
  import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

  @Injectable()
  export class UserDataService{
   public data : Object;

   constructor(private http : Http){}

   getUserData(){
      this.http.get('./config.json').map((res:Response)=>res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {this.data = data});

   return this.data;
   }
```

}

I want to check if a certain variable exists in that config file, and if it does I want to show the div, but the problem is the view does not refresh like I thought it would. I clearly am not grasping the situation so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async processing works a bit different.

```
export class AppComponent {
     public data : Object;

     constructor(private userDataService : UserDataService) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       // subscribe and assign result when it arrives to `this.data`
       this.userDataService.getUserData().subscribe(data => this.data = data); 
     }

}
```

Use `.map()` instead of `subscribe()` so an `Observable` is reaturned instead of a `Subscription` to allow the caller to get notified when the data arrives.

Add an actual `return` if you want to use the result on call site:

```
getUserData() {
    return this.http.get('./config.json')
    .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
//    .map(data => {this.data = data});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this still does not work for me. I am going to read some more into it to find the solution.

Comment: I forgot to remove a line (commented it out now). https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html should contain a few examples.

Comment: It still doesn't work, so I will consult the docs you mentioned.

Comment: If you are trying to fetch data that has been loaded by another component in the app than you need to share the same instance of the service.  let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage(),http);


bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
  [provide(AuthService,{useValue:authService})],
]).catch(err => console.error(err));

Comment: @rashfmnb I don't see how this is related.

Comment: What you are explaining is to share a service between different Angular applications.

Comment: Actually i have use this same way to share the service instance between components otherwise it was behaving the same each time when i call the getdata method it gives me the new instance of the data because for every component it was creating new instance of service

Comment: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [AuthService])` is sufficient. Just don't add it to providers of any component. For this question it doesn't apply because it doesn't matter if the same or a different instance of the service is used because nothing is shared. Just a call to the service that calls to a server and returns some data. This works no matter how often the service is called.